# MySQL query from multiple tables, main table and meta table

Tags: mysql, sql

How would u suggest to construct queries, if I have 2 tables like

Table **'posts'**

```
  ID   |   post_cat   |   post_type   |   post_date
  1    |   1          |   0           |   xyz        
  2    |   3          |   1           |   xyz
```

Table **'post_meta'**

```
p_id   |   meta_key   |   meta_value
1      |   name       |   John
1      |   location   |   NY
1      |   age        |   31
2      |   name       |   Jane
2      |   age        |   26
```

Reqs:
1. I'd like to get results like:

```
 ID |  post_cat |  post_type |  post_date |  name |     location  |  age 
 1  |    1      |    0       |      xyz   |  john |      NY       |  31
 2  |    3      |    1       |       xyz  |  Jane |               |  26
```

2. How u suggest to make the query when I try to get results based on post_meta > meta_key; eg searching for posts, where post_meta.meta_key=location and meta_value=NY?

Comment: Plz show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use a JOIN between the tables. If you want multiple meta_keys per result row, JOIN with the post_meta table multiple times, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
JOIN post_meta m ON p.id = m.p_id
WHERE m.meta_key = 'location' AND m.meta_value = 'NY'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
JOIN post_meta mn ON p.id = mn.p_id AND mn.meta_key = 'name'
JOIN post_meta ma ON p.id = ma.p_id AND ma.meta_key = 'age'
```

You can list which columns you actually want instead of all (`*`). You may also want to use `LEFT JOIN` if a particular meta_key may be optional.

Comment: Don't post answers without explaining them. The OP does not get anything from the answer to learn.

Comment: @Ama Added an introductory sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In the first matter you want to have pivoting which could be done through conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT ID, post_cat, post_type, post_date, 
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'name' then m.meta_value end) as name,
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'location' then m.meta_value end) as location,
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'age' then m.meta_value end) as age
  FROM posts p
  JOIN post_meta m
    ON m.p_id = p.ID
 GROUP BY ID, post_cat, post_type, post_date
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13a6268a90a0ed9a2b68a3d1612dc55c)</kbd>

I don't understand what is meant in the second one.